# How to send string compressed with GZIP from Java App to PHP web service

Tags: java, php, android, json, gzip

I have this issue with GZIP compression:

I need to send by POST method a huge JSON string, which is too big to be accept like URL (Ex: http://localhost/app/send/**JSON STRING ENCODED BY BASE64**), than it result in HTTP error 403

so, I need to compress my json and I found a way to do it with GZIP compression, which I can decompress with gzdecode() in PHP.

but it doesn't work...

my functions compress() and decompress() works fine inside my Java App, but when I send it to webservice, something goes wrong and gzdecode() doesn't work. 
I have no idea what I missing, I need some help

functions used in java app (client)

```
    public String Post(){
     String retorno = "";
     String u = compress(getInput());
     u = URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(u, "UTF-8"));

     URL uri = new URL(url + u);

     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

     conn.setDoOutput(false);
     conn.setRequestMethod(getMethod());

     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-encoding", "gzip");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

     BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

     String r = "";
     while ((r = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                retorno = r + "\n";
     }
     return retorno;
}
```

GZIP compress function (client)

```
public static String compress(String str) throws IOException {

        byte[] blockcopy = ByteBuffer
                .allocate(4)
                .order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                .putInt(str.length())
                .array();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(str.length());
        GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
        gos.write(str.getBytes());
        gos.close();
        os.close();
        byte[] compressed = new byte[4 + os.toByteArray().length];
        System.arraycopy(blockcopy, 0, compressed, 0, 4);
        System.arraycopy(os.toByteArray(), 0, compressed, 4,
                os.toByteArray().length);

        return Base64.encode(compressed);

    }
```

method php used to receive a URL (server, using Slim/PHP Framework)

```
init::$app->post('/enviar/:obj/', function( $obj ) {
     $dec = base64_decode(urldecode( $obj ));//decode url and decode base64 tostring
     $dec = gzdecode($dec);//here is my problem, gzdecode() doesn't work
}
```

post method

```
public Sender() throws JSONException {   
    //
    url = "http://192.168.0.25/api/index.php/enviar/";
    method = "POST";
    output = true;
    //
}
```

Comment: Don't use `str.getBytes()`; you don't specify the encoding. And in fact you don't specify it in the data you send either. Same for `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: How can I specify encoding to InputStreamReader?

Comment: As is very often the case, [the javadoc has the answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Comment: Ok, I supposed to use regular UTF-8 encoding or something else specific for GZIP compression?

Comment: Choosing an encoding has nothing to do with compression; you will of course encode before you compress, but that you use UTF-8 + gzip (recommended) or, who knows, EBCDIC + compress, the principle is the same: characters -> stream of bytes -> compressed stream of bytes (which you then encode in BASE64 in your case)

Comment: So, it's possible that base64 encode are corrupting my compression? Cuz' it doesn't work like it was supposed to... 
My steps are: json -> gzip compress -> base64 encode -> URL encoding
Than..
Receive by POST in php  and URL decode -> base64 decode -> gzip decompress and here it brokes...
There's something wrong in this steps?

Comment: Well, the first thing is that Java's `URLEncoder` deals with POST data, not URI components; second, well, why isn't this a POST request?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using POST request, i'll edit with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed in some of the comments.

1. Bigger data should be send as a POST request instead of GET. URL params should be used only for single variables. As you noticed the URL length is limited to few kB and it's not very good idea to send larger data this way (even though GZIP compressed).
2. Your GZIP compression code seems to be wrong. Please try this:

```java
  public static String compress(String str) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(str.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
    gos.write(str.getBytes());
    os.close();
    gos.close();
    return Base64.encodeToString(os.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
  }
```

Comment: Lat line should be: return Base64.encodeToString(os.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);